# About the usage of yield in python

Tags: python-2.7

i write this code:

```
def frange(start, end, increase):
x = start
while x < end:
    yield x
    x = x + increase

print(list(frange(1, 2, 0.3)))
```

the output is:

```
[1, 1.3, 1.6, 1.9000000000000001]
```

but i don't know why the last element is `1.9000000000000001` other than `1.9`.
Could you tell me the reason?

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with `yield`, but with the limitation of representing floating point values. Python's just [more honest](http://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) than languages that hide this from you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consume the doc of [Floating Point Arithmetic: Issues and Limitations](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) to know the reason.

Comment: Python is too honest.